# Passport.authenticate not sending a response

Tags: passport.js

I'm using Passport for authentication, specifically with a JWT strategy. I'm able to create a new token when a user is created, however, when I use that token in the header of a request to a route that requires authentication, my request just hangs up. I'm using Postman to test these POST/GET requests.

**Here's my initial configuration for signing up a user:**

```
const User = require('../db/models/User');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

function userToken(user) {
  return jwt.sign({
    id: user.id,
  }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
}

exports.signup = function(req, res, next) {
  const email = req.body.email.toLowerCase();
  const password = req.body.password.toLowerCase();

  User.findOne({
    where: { email },
  }).then(function(user) {
    if (!user) {
      User.create({
        email,
        password,
      })
      .then(function(user) {
        return res.send({ token: userToken(user) });
      });
    }
    if (user) {
      return res.send({ message: 'That user is in use' });
    }
  });
};
```

**Here's my passport configuration:**

```
const passport = require('passport');
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const User = require('../db/models/User');

const jwtOptions = {
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromHeader('authorization'),
  secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
};

const jwtLogin = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, function(payload, done) {
  User.findOne({
    where: { id: payload.id },
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) { return done(err, false); }
    if (user) { return done(null, user); }
    return done(null, false);
  });
});

passport.use(jwtLogin);
```

**Here's what my protected route looks like:**

```
const passport = require('passport');

const requireAuth = passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false });

module.exports = function router(app) {
  app.get('/', requireAuth, function(req, res) {
    res.send({ 'hi': 'there' });
  });
};
```

**Here's what I see in my terminal:**

```
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "username", "email", "password", "photo", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "users" AS "user" WHERE "user"."id" = 15;
```

So I know that it's correctly querying for a user id and searching for it, however, it just hangs up at this point, rather than serving me a response.

Not sure what the issue is, so any and all suggestions are welcomed and appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Realized that because I am using Sequelize, it handles errors with a catch like so:

```
...

const jwtLogin = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, function(payload, done) {
  User.findOne({
    where: { id: payload.id }
  })
  .then(user => {
    if (user) {
      done(null, user);
    } else {
      done(null, false);
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    if (err) { return done(err, false); }
  });
});

...
```

This solved my issue and is returning my response.